# Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop-full

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this ubuntu:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

I have followed everything from the page [Ubuntu install of ROS Lunar][1].

I did everything on this page, but when I do:

> sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-desktop-full

I get the following message:

```
Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop-full
```

Is there something I can check to find why it isn't finding the package?

I have added mirrors from Ireland, Germany and Netherlands but it cannot locate the package.
[1]: http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288935/unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-desktop-full/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're using Ubuntu 17.10, but it's not supported on that distribution. From [ROS REP-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019)

> ### Lunar Loggerhead (May 2017 - May 2019)
>
> Required Support for:
>
> - Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)
> - Ubuntu Yakkety (16.10)
> - Ubuntu Zesty (17.04)

[Melodic is supported on 17.10](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019), however

> ### Melodic Morenia (May 2018 - May 2023)
>
> Required Support for:
>
> - Ubuntu Artful (17.10)
> - Ubuntu Bionic (18.04)

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-18**:
The REP is explicit about this, but it's also stated on the wiki page @VansFannel linked to. Under `Ubuntu install of ROS Lunar` there is no mention of `Artful` anywhere.